# c# Using enum in Switch Case throwing exception

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement, .net-6.0

I am working on .NET 6.0 application, I have enum that I am trying to use in switch as to compare with string value but getting exception.

`error`

[image: ![enter code here]

```
private static bool ValidateAlphanumericCase(string text, string fieldName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fieldName))
        {
            var rule = GetRule(fieldName).TxtFieldFormat; // string value

            switch (rule)
            {
                case TextFieldFormat.AlphanumericUpperCase.ToString():
                    break;

                case TextFieldFormat.AlphanumericLowerCase.ToString():
                    break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            new EmptyFieldNameException();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

`enum`

```
 public enum TextFieldFormat
{
    AlphanumericUpperCase = 0,
    AlphanumericLowerCase = 1,
}
```

Comment: That's a compilation error, not an exception. Unless it's a bogus Intellisense error. Does your code compile? Post the actual compilation error in the question instead of images

Comment: `AlphanumericUpperCase` is in enum class further If I print this as `var b = TextFieldFormat.AlphanumericUpperCase.ToString();` then it does work so not sure why not in `case`?

Comment: Don't describe what you already posted. Post the actual code and actual compilation error. Perhaps there's no error, just an Intellisense bug. Or perhaps you're using the wrong namespace. If you created a Console app with just the enum declaration and the `switch` you wouldn't get any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextFieldFormat.AlphanumericUpperCase.ToString()
```

This is a method invocation expression and it is not a valid pattern for swith statement.

You can find all valid patterns here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns

The closest pattern is type pattern or constant pattern, I guess the compiler recognizes `AlphanumericUpperCase` as a nested class of `TextFieldFormat` and fails.

In this case you can use nameof operator.

```
 switch (rule)
 {
      case nameof(TextFieldFormat.AlphanumericUpperCase):
          break;
      case nameof(TextFieldFormat.AlphanumericLowerCase):
          break;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you understood `switch-case` block a little bit different.

A `switch` block is simply a shortcut (but more performant shortcut) of many `if - else if - else` blocks.
Of course they are not the same, but their working logic almost the same.

With this very little info, you can easily think about what's wrong in your code.

Bingo, you're right! `Case` blocks should check the state. (`Boolean` value..Just interests with either the given statement results `true` or `false`..)

After checking the `boolean` result,  Which `case`'s statement match, code continues on that `case` block.

So, in your situation your code could be like this :

```
switch (rule)
{
    
/// Some statements need to put in paranthesis. Also you would need put business codes of cases into curly braces.
/// I write from my mind.
/// So please try paranthesis and/or braces if this code break.

case rule==TextFieldFormat.AlphanumericUpperCase.ToString():
DoSomethingWithFirstCase(); break;

case rule==TextFieldFormat.AlphanumericLowerCase.ToString():
DoSomethingWitSecondCase(); break;

default: DoSomethingWhenNoMatchWithOtherCases();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use it this way

```
TextFieldFormat.AlphanumericUpperCase.ToString("g" or "G")
```